# Calculate week number within month

Tags: c#, culture

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Calculate week of month in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2136487/calculate-week-of-month-in-net)

I need to calculate the week number of a given Date within a **month**. The reason I embolden month is that all the examples (on here and elsehwere) I come across are based on yearly. Basically, I want to see what week number 14/2/2010 comes in (dd/MM/yyyy format). Given a starting day of Monday, I would expect this to return 2.

How aware of Culture do I have to be in this calculation?

Comment: This is effectively a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2136487/get-week-of-month-in-net/2136549#2136549.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is effectively a duplicate of [Get Week of Month in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2136487/get-week-of-month-in-net/2136549#2136549). You need to alter the method `GetWeekOfYear` shown there to account for the fact that you want your weeks to start on Monday.

This answer intentionally marked Community Wiki.

Comment: Thanks, Jason. Sorry for the dupe. I guess I was searching on "Calculate" instead of "Get". Also search in list of potentials in subject but no match.

Comment: @Program.X: You're welcome. Yes, that's a bad title for that question. I'll fix.