# calulate month from week no

Tags: c#, asp.net, culture

i am getting week no from database need to calculate which week of the month it is.

for ex:

```
week no = 7 month = 2

week no 11 month = 3
```

How to calculate it??

Just to add on i also have the year value with the week no.

Comment: What if a week spans two months?

Comment: But if the week is between two months?

Comment: @Øyvind Knobloch-Bråthen notable quest

Comment: This is tricky. You need to know the year too. Also there are several ways to determine what the first week is (4 days or more, first Sunday, first full workweek)

Comment: @Marco if the week is between two months i need only month that belong to start date of the week

Comment: @ankur - For only the start date, I have a working solution below. The GregorianCalendar can help you skip the ugly code of getting the weeknumber for a date yourself, and at least make the code short even if it's not very pretty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I'll have a go, but it's not very pretty:

```
public int MonthOfWeek( int week, int year, CalendarWeekRule, weekrule, DayOfWeek firstDayOfWeek)
{
  GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar();
  for( DateTime dt = new DateTime(year, 1, 1); dt.Year == year; dt = dt.AddDays(1))
  {
    if( gc.GetWeekOfYear( dt, System.Globalization.CalendarWeekRule.FirstFourDayWeek, DayOfWeek.Monday) == week ){
      return dt.Month;
    }
  }
  return -1;
}
```

This takes into consideration the culture specific rules for generating weeks. If a week is split between two months it will return the first month it encounters.

So in Norway, I would call this with `CalendarWeekRule.FirstFourDayWeek` and `DayOfWeek.Monday` for correct results.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you are looking for the month in the given year:

```
var dtYearStart = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 1, 1);
CultureInfo defaultCultureInfo = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;

// Check for the starting date of the initial week.
int diff = dtYearStart.DayOfWeek - defaultCultureInfo.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek;
if (diff < 0)
{
 diff += 7;
}

dtYearStart = dtYearStart.AddDays(-1 * diff).Date;

int weekNo = 15;

DateTime dtWeekBased = dtYearStart.AddDays((weekNo-1) * 7);
string strMonth  = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(dtWeekBased.Month);
```

Comment: I think you should add `(weekNo-1)*7`, am I wrong? Anyway, +1 because it's a good answer! :)

Comment: Does not work - the first calendar week of a year may start in December of the previous year.

Comment: @Marco: I just checked, yes it should be weekNo-1, thanks. I've updated.

Comment: You are not sure that the first week will be the first 7 days of the year. This will not always give the correct result.

Comment: @Thortsten, if the week starts in the previous year it shouldn't matter as adding on additional weeks will always push the date into a subsequent relative date for the correct week index.

Comment: @Thorsten, actually, I see the problem now. The month is the actual start date of the week. Ok, I'll ammend shortly.

Comment: @Brian Scott - Will work some places I guess. This week thing is highly culture specific. In Norway, the first week of the year is the first week that has at least 4 days, and the first day of week is Monday. So if 29.12.2010 was a Monday, that Monday belongs to week 1 of 2011, but if it was on 28.12.2010 it belongs to week 52/53 of 2010.

Comment: @Thorston, I've updated the initial day of the week type for different cultures.

Answer (score 2):

Calculate a date from weeknumber:

[Calculate date from week number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/662379/calculate-date-from-week-number)

Get the WeekOfMonth:

[Calculate week of month in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2136487/calculate-week-of-month-in-net)

Answer (score 0):

Using DateTime, you can multiply week number by 7, get the total days passed on the year, add those days to 31/12/yyyy-1 and the get the month from the resulting DateTime.

I hope this to be useful to you.

See you.

Comment: Does not work - the first calendar week of a year may start in December of the previous year.

Comment: I understand, you have to set then 31/12/yyyy-1? Sorry for the mistake, I will edit now

Comment: @Amedio - How the weeks is generated is dependent on culture specific settings also. This will not always provide the correct results unfortunately.

Comment: @Oyvind - Then my solution would only work correctly where the weeks long 7 days and the years long 365/366 days?

Comment: @Amedio - What does it help subtracting one day from 31.12.yyyy? The first day of week 1 can (in Norway) be either day from 28.12.yyyy-1 to 3.1.yyyy. It depends on which day of week the new year starts on.

Comment: @Oyvind - Ooook, I understand now, if I just multiply with 7, I will became in an error, if my year doesn't start in Monday/Sunday (Depending of the culture) I'm correct?

Answer (score 0):

4 week = 1 month
so use

week%4

its return you no of month

Comment: 4 weeks != 1 month. 4 weeks = 4*7 days = 28 days. Only February qualify for this (at least most years). This is as inaccurate as you can get it.

Comment: but he want only month from a week not days from a week

Comment: First of, I guess you mean week/4 (also division, and not modulus). It still wont work. An example: Week 14 is 4.-10. April. Yet, 14/4 = 3.5 indicating March. If you are thinking that January is 0 and not 1, then it gets correct for week 14, since 3 is April, but for week 51 for example (19.-25. December) you will get 51/4 = 12.75 indicating that week 51 belongs to the 13th month of the year. Doesn't give much sense. Since a month is **not** 4 weeks, you can't simply divide by 4 to get the correct result.

Answer (score 0):

Here a solution using the [Time Period Library for .NET](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/datetime/TimePeriod.aspx):

```
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
public int GetMonthOfWeek( int weekOfYear )
{
  return new Week( weekOfYear ).FirstDayStart.Month;
} // GetMonthOfWeek
```