# Displaying days on a custom calendar wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, observablecollection

I'm trying to display the days of the month on a custom calendar in the right spot. Using binding and using observable collection I have a  grid with 7 columns and 6 rows, I need to display the date(number) on each textBlock. I've gotten myself to a point that I'm completely lost and I don't know what else to try. Somehow I need to get the day of week and what day it is. I'm not even sure if I'm going about this the right way. I know the XAML is good(should be at least) I'm confused on using datetime and observable collections though. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Here I use Observable collection:

```
public SchedulePage(MainWindow parentForm)
{
   InitializeComponent();
   _parentForm = parentForm;
   // DateTime date = new DateTime(year, month, day);

   _parentForm.bindings = new BindingCamper();

   int day = DateTime.DaysInMonth(2011, 10);

   for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
   {
      for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++)
      {
         _parentForm.bindings.schedule.Add(new Schedule { WeekNo = i, WeekDay = j });
         DataContext = _parentForm.bindings;
      }
    }
}
```

This is a Schedule class I have:

```
public class Schedule //: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public int WeekNo { get; set; }
    public int WeekDay { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public int datenum
    {
        get { return (int)Date.DayOfWeek; }
    }
}
```

And the XAML:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding schedule}" Name="Calender" Margin="0,34,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
  <ItemsControl.Template>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ItemsControl" >
        <Border BorderBrush="Aqua" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="15">
            <ItemsPresenter/>
        </Border>

    </ControlTemplate>



  </ItemsControl.Template>
<!-- ItemsPanelTemplate -->
  <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

    <ItemsPanelTemplate>

        <Grid ShowGridLines="True" Name="gridCalender">

            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        </Grid>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>

    <DataTemplate>

        <TextBlock Text ="{Binding datenum}" Background="#FFBCF4E0" OpacityMask="Black" Grid.Column="{Binding datenum}" />


    </DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>


<!-- ItemContainerStyle -->
 <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style >
        <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="{Binding WeekDay}" />
        <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="{Binding WeekNo}" />

    </Style>
 </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
</ItemsControl>
```

I also have a class creating a new ObservableCollection();

Answer (score 0):

Your loop for creating the dates should probably be a loop through Dates, with the WeekNo and WeekDay being values calculated based on the date

For example,

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Now;
DateTime startDate = new DateTime(today.Year, today.Month, 1);
DateTime endDate = startDate.AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1);

while (startDate <= endDate)
{
    DayCollection.Add(new Day
    {
        Date = startDate,
        WeekDay = (int)startDate.DayOfWeek,
        WeekNo = startDate.GetWeekOfMonth()
    });

    startDate = startDate.AddDays(1);
}
```

It uses an Extension Method to find the week number within the month, which can be found [on another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2136487/calculate-week-of-month-in-net/2136549#2136549)

```
static class DateTimeExtensions
{
    static GregorianCalendar _gc = new GregorianCalendar();
    public static int GetWeekOfMonth(this DateTime time)
    {
        DateTime first = new DateTime(time.Year, time.Month, 1);
        return time.GetWeekOfYear() - first.GetWeekOfYear() + 1;
    }

    static int GetWeekOfYear(this DateTime time)
    {
        return _gc.GetWeekOfYear(time, CalendarWeekRule.FirstDay, DayOfWeek.Sunday);
    }
}
```