# Linq date to weeks: google visualisation line chart JSON format

Tags: c#, json, linq, google-visualization

I have data returned in this format:

---

|  Name | WeeklyTotal | WeekEnd      |

---

Name1  |     2     | 2014-03-07 
 Name2  |       4     | 2014-01-03 
 Name1  |      3      | 2014-02-28 
 Name3  |      3      | 2014-03-07

etc. I am trying to project this data on a chart, using google visualization. I need a linq statement that will group data into a object like:
    Week1 => { Name1 = 2, Name2 = 0, Name3 = 3}

Basically, for each week, return an object with Weekly totals for each Name on the list. I have not an idea of how I am even going to approach this.

Comment: Are the names known ahead of time? Is the "object" for the grouping just some sort of dynamic JSON object (e.g. using Json.NET)?

Comment: I am looking for somthing similar to these: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15927573/c-sharp-linq-or-lambda-expresion-group-by-week-ienumerable-list-with-date-field

Comment: That doesn't really help to clarify it much for me, as we still don't know whether `Name1`, `Name2` etc are fixed or whether they vary. It's also not clear why you'd want 2014-03-07 to be "Week1"... what week numbering system are you interested in?

Comment: It doesnt necessarily have to be week1. I just need to group those items by week, for each name in the name column. I have a query:

   select count(ListingID) WeeklyTotal, name, WeekStart from ( 
           select id, name, dateadd(week,datediff(day,'20000107',Datetime) / 7, '20000107') AS WeekStart from table ) as u group by name, WeekStart

this, returns weeklytotal for each person, and the friday of that week. Now, from that data, I need to put different names with the same week ending in the same object. I hope that makes sense?

Comment: Well you *still* haven't answered whether the "name" part is fixed or dynamic... which affects whether or not this can be done through an anonymous type, or whether it'll have to be more dynamic.