# Assistance needed on the last part of Managing Backups According to SLA

Tags: powershell, backup

As an update to my question earlier I will post the script I have up to now, the first two tasks I have managed to script perfectly, leaving me with backups younger than 30 days and, when older, only backups created on sundays. However, I am unable to get the 3rd task out of the way. Could anyone please provide me with some pointer as to how I can accomplish the 3rd task? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Here is my code sofar:

```
Function FirstCheck{

$Today = GET-Date

#Check for *.BAK files to see if older than 30 days.
$BackupsOlderThan30 = GET-CHILDITEM C:\Temp\OnTracBak\ –filter *.BAK | WHERE { (($Today - $_.LastWriteTime).Days –gt 30 ) }

#Check for files older than 30 days and that are not Sunday
$NotWeeklyBackups=$BackupsOlderThan30 | where { ($_.LastWriteTime ).DayOfWeek –ne ’Sunday’ }

$NotWeeklyBackups | REMOVE-ITEM

$NotWeeklyBackups.Count

}
```

I might have a question/little challenge for you.
I'll try to explain it as clear as possible.

Situation:
Our company uses an SLA for our customers.

One of the items in this SLA is a backup clause...
In here we defined a couple of rules:

1. for the first 30 days from today a backup should be made and kept daily.
2. for the the second and third month a backup should be kept every week
3. for the fourth till the twentyfourth month a backup should be kept monthly.

Now, the backups are made on a daily basis.
As a result, our backupfolder currently has a size of around 4TB. (Way to large.)

Of course we could track and delete or save our backupfiles manually but of course, I would like to automate this using Powershell scripting.

The script should do the following:
Check the folder and subfolder for .bak and .trn files.
Get the date of these files and apply the following rules:

1. If files are between 1 and 30 days old, keep all the files.
2. If files are between the second and third month old, keep a full backup every week (sunday) (delete other backup files to which 2. applies)
3. If files are between the fourth and the twentyfourth month old, keep a full backup from evey 4th week of the month... (delete other backupfiles to which 3. applies)

Currently I have no idea as to how or where to begin scripting or obviously how to perform these extended searches ... :-(

Answer (score 1):

Use `Get-ChildItem` cmdlet to list the files. Each file has got a `LastWriteTime` property, by whic you can filter the collection. Business rules for filtering are left as an exercise to the reader. Simple filtering example is like so,

```
$files = @(gci path-to-files) # Force gci to return an array
$cutPoint = (get-date).addDays(-30) # Get date 30 days ago
$filesToPrune = $files | ? { $_.LastWriteTime -lt $cutPoint } # Files for archive process
```

Comment: Thanks for the partial answer on this one..
As of now I've found a way to make the first two tasks work, however, I am not getting the last one to work, I have will update my question with the current solution I have, but would like to ask your or anyone's help here to get task #3 to work... thanks in advance!

Comment: @RoelofW What you need is to formalize the SLA rules. A verbal explanation is just the starting point. Write out a pseudocode implementation, and then start to work on it with Powershell. Calculating "n-th week of month" is locale specific. For example, in the US, Sunday is the 1st day of a week whlist Monday is the 1st day in many other locales.

Comment: @RoleofW How about re-defining the SLA a bit? For the elder backup sets, just keep the last full backup for every month. No need to calculate the n-th week.

Comment: @vonPrynx What needs to be done is; I need to figure out, from the files that are left after my "firstcheck" function (which works like a charm), which of the files are older than 4 months and delete everything that is not equal to the fourth (or last) week of the month... indeed, I need to keep the last full backup for every month, but... I am stuck on how to determine the last backup of every month...

Comment: @RoelofW Please post separate a question for the nth week of a month calculation. The issue is not simple. There are some [C# solutions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2136487/calculate-week-of-month-in-net), that can be converted into PSH with little effort.