# LocalDate from month and day of week in NodaTime

Tags: c#, .net, date, dayofweek, nodatime

I'm looking to construct a date from a description such as "The second Monday in March, 2014".
How would I go about doing so? `LocalDate`'s [`FromWeekYearWeekAndDay`](http://nodatime.org/1.2.x/api/html/M_NodaTime_LocalDate_FromWeekYearWeekAndDay.htm) seems like a start, but as I said, I'm hoping to provide the week of the month, not the week of the year.

Comment: Sounds as if this is a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2136487/calculate-week-of-month-in-net

Comment: That may be a good starting point, but note that this is using [NodaTime](http://nodatime.org/)

Comment: Do you actually need to parse a string of text like the example you gave?  Or do you have separate variables for each piece already?

Comment: @MattJohnson: The latter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could most certainly be refined, but here is a function that will work:

```
public static LocalDate GetDay(int year, int month, IsoDayOfWeek dayOfWeek,
                                                                    int instance)
{
    int daysInMonth = CalendarSystem.Iso.GetDaysInMonth(year, month);

    var ld = new LocalDate(year, month, 1);
    if (ld.IsoDayOfWeek != dayOfWeek)
        ld = ld.Next(dayOfWeek);
    for (int i = 1; i < instance && ld.Day + 7 <= daysInMonth; i++)
        ld = ld.PlusWeeks(1);
    return ld;
}
```

You can pass 5 for the instance if you want the *last* one, which might fall on the 4th or 5th week.

Refinements might include support for other calendars, and better use of modulo math to avoid loops.

(A [feature request](https://code.google.com/p/noda-time/issues/detail?id=293) has been filed, and may well be supported in 2.0.)