# How do I get which week of the month belong the selected date

Tags: .net, vb.net

How do I get which week of the month belong the selected date .

For Example : I choose March 2 , It will show "week 1" . If I choose March 23 , It will show "week 4" ..

Comment: march 2 is from week 1 right..is it typing mistake?

Comment: http://vbcity.com/forums/t/151885.aspx and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2136487/calculate-week-of-month-in-net