# Newtonsoft deserializing Json incorrectly

Tags: json, f#, json.net

I have encountered a case where Newtonsoft is taking perfectly valid JSON text, but deserializing it incorrectly.  I have an object that contains an embedded class that consists of members Year, Month, Week, and DayOfWk.  The JSON looks like this:

```
 "openDate": {
  "Year": 1997,
  "Month": 12,
  "Week": 5,
  "DayOfWk": 5
 },
```

But the data that comes back after deserialization is Year = 1, Month = 1, Week = 1, and DayOfWk = 1, regardless of the input JSON.

Here is the code (it's in F#, but should be easily readable):

```
  let jsonText = File.ReadAllText( @"..\..\..\..\Dependencies\ADBE.dat")
  let dailyData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DailyAnalysis[]>(jsonText)
```

DailyAnalysis is defined as:

```
type DailyAnalysis = {
openDate: TradeDate
openPrice: Decimal
closeDate: TradeDate
closePrice: Decimal
gainPercentage: Decimal
}
```

TradeDate is the class in question - it is an F# class that exposes properties Year, Month, Week, and DayOfWk.  Year, Month, and Week are int's; DayOfWeek is a DayOfWeek enum.  All the other fields in the DailyAnalysis objects come back with the correct values.

How can this problem be resolved?

Note that if I don't include the type in the DeserializeObject call, it does get the correct data, but simply returns it as an object, and converting to the correct type is very difficult (i.e., I don't know how to do it in F#).

Can anybody point out something obvious (or even obscure) I'm overlooking, or point me to other resources?

**Update:** note that the constructor for `TradeDate` takes a single `DateTime` argument.

Comment: Can you share the `TradeDate` type -- i.e. a [mcve]?

Comment: Can't reproduce with a simple example, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/dxeHt9

Comment: All I can guess is that the argument names to the `TradeDate` constructor don't match the property names.  Json.NET matches constructor arguments to properties by using the argument name, so if the names are inconsistent a default value is passed in.  See https://dotnetfiddle.net/YSvyVy.  But without a [mcve] we can only guess.

Comment: dbc - I think your last point may be the answer - the constructor takes a single DateTime agrument, and of course, Json is not going to have anyway to know what that is.  I will explore other ways to structure that. Thanks.

Comment: Don't have time to check right now, but could it be an eager eval issue? Change `letJsonText = ...` to `letJsonText () = ...`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your `TradeDate` is immutable (as typically happens in f#), then Json.NET is able to deserialize such a type by finding a single constructor which is parameterized, then invoking it by matching constructor arguments to JSON properties by name, modulo case.  Arguments that do not match are given a default value.  If `TradeDate` actually takes a single `DateTime` as input, you will get the behavior you are seeing.

For instance, if we take a simplified version like so:

```
type TradeDate(date : DateTime) = 
    member this.Year = date.Year
    member this.Month = date.Month
    member this.DayOfMonth = date.Day
```

And then round-trip it using Json.NET as follows:

```
let t1 = new TradeDate(new DateTime(1997, 12, 25))
let json1 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(t1)
let t2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TradeDate>(json1)
let json2 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(t2)

printfn "\nResult after round-trip:\n%s" json2
```

The result becomes:

```
{"Year":1,"Month":1,"DayOfMonth":1}
```

Which is exactly what you are seeing.  Demo fiddle #1 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/79vbrJ).

So, what are your options?  Firstly, you could modify `TradeDate` to have the necessary constructor, and mark it with [`JsonConstructor`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonConstructorAttribute.htm).  It could be private as long as the attribute is applied:

```
type TradeDate [<JsonConstructor>] private(year : int, month : int, dayOfMonth: int) = 
    member this.Year = year
    member this.Month = month
    member this.DayOfMonth = dayOfMonth

    new(date : DateTime) = new TradeDate(date.Year, date.Month, date.Day)
```

Demo fiddle #2 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/vwwdsw).

Secondly, if you cannot modify `TradeDate` or add Json.NET attributes to it, you could introduce a [custom `JsonConverter`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm) for it:

```
[<AllowNullLiteral>] type private TradeDateDTO(year : int, month : int, dayOfMonth : int) =
    member this.Year = year
    member this.Month = month
    member this.DayOfMonth = dayOfMonth

type TradeDateConverter () =
    inherit JsonConverter()

    override this.CanConvert(t) = (t = typedefof<TradeDate>)

    override this.ReadJson(reader, t, existingValue, serializer) = 
        let dto = serializer.Deserialize<TradeDateDTO>(reader)
        match dto with
        | null -> raise (new JsonSerializationException("null TradeDate"))
        | _ -> new TradeDate(new DateTime(dto.Year, dto.Month, dto.DayOfMonth)) :> Object

    override this.CanWrite = false

    override this.WriteJson(writer, value, serializer) = 
        raise (new NotImplementedException());
```

And deserialize as follows:

```
let converter = new TradeDateConverter()
let t2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TradeDate>(json1, converter)
```

Demo fiddle #3 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Q7Cfe9).

Notes:

1. Your question did not include code for `TradeDate`, in particular the code for converting between a `DateTime` and the year/month/week of month/day of week representation.  This turns out to be slightly nontrivial so I did not include it in the answer; see *[Calculate week of month in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2136487/3744182)* and *[Calculate date from week number](https://stackoverflow.com/q/662379/3744182)* for how this might be done.
2. For details on how Json.NET chooses which constructor to invoke for a type with multiple constructors, see *[How does JSON deserialization in C# work](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41870132/3744182)*.